# res file not found exception

Tags: android

I am getting this "java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-nodpi/background.xml".
But I do have a file in

$

```
 ls -la res/drawable-nodpi/background.xml 
-rw-r--r--  1 michael  staff  859 Mar  8 09:28 res/drawable-nodpi/background.xml


E/AndroidRuntime(  301): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-nodpi/background.xml
E/AndroidRuntime(  301):        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  301):        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(  301):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1894)
```

Comment: I think if you're using the Resources class, you need to put xml under the right directory.  What's your configuration?  Did you see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html

Comment: what SDK version you compiling with ?

Comment: Could also be a syntax error in your xml file causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the `drawable-nodpi` folder is for pre-scaling of images. I would suggest putting it in the `drawable` folder.

If that doesn't help, try cleaning your project and take a look at the `gen/your_package/R.Java` to see if the file is indeed included in the package.